# How can I use Google Maps?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

My `application.js` has this:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Of of the scripts in the tree (`create_maps.js`) needs Google Maps. How can I include the Google Maps script from Google CDN and load it before my `create-maps.js` runs?

Comment: Is the javascript being loaded from the correct location in the asset pipeline? I recently ran into an issue where plugin js was not following the proper path for the asset pipeline to load it. If you are not already using [Chrome/Firefox developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript) I suggest checking those out. Using them properly can be a huge help in troubleshooting asset loading issues.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to see some code, but it sounds like you have the classic javascript timing issue, whereby your application code is running before the dependencies have been loaded. Have you seen [this article on Object-Oriented javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). Generally the article explains the Closure and Wrapping pattern to properly encapsulate your javascript into the correct scope.

If you create an initialization function inside Create_maps which only exposes the public methods required by your application, you can then call these within a Document.Ready function in your main page, this will make sure that your code is not called until the full page has been loaded (dependencies as well).